# html/css image doesn't expand parent element on browser resize

Tags: html, css

#### Primarily I'm looking for answer whether this is intended behaviour or a browser bug..

Can't believe  I have never encountered this problem before, am I doing something obviously wrong?

http://jsbin.com/baroqudafayu/1/edit?output

Try resizing the browser, images resizes, parent(`.item`) stays same width. Unless I manually trigger repaint/reflow. Note that it does work fine on load.

The html/css is nothing special.

```
 <div class="wrap">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.starplugins.com/sites/starplugins/images/jetzoom/large/image2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.starplugins.com/sites/starplugins/images/jetzoom/large/image2.jpg" alt="">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

-

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50000px;
  height: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;

  img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

I've tried changing inline-block on `.item` to block/float, as well as changing combinations display, max-height, max-width, height, width on pretty much everything. Nothing helped.

edit:

#### additional info

- should work in IE8
- the reason `.item` is there, is to be able to potentially add overlay(with position absolute, widht/height 100%) and show it on hover.

Comment: _Are those supposed to be curly braces? Like `{}`._ nevermind I misunderstood your code as... code.

Comment: @flowstoneknight ......... I just wanted to give a quick overview of the structure and essential css properties, instead of posting two blocks of full code. Check the jsbin link.

Comment: @C-linkNepal that never ceases to amaze me. Much clearer now, eh? I actually did put effort by making is as easily readable as possible, intead of posting bunch of "not-so-much-on-first-sight-clear" code. What do you think is faster, what I did, or copy&pasting code from jsbin.

Comment: Your .item height changes because it's in percent.. your width is not

Comment: It should matter, should it? width should expand along with width of the inner element, which is not absolutely positioned or anything. Also it works fine on load and when I trigger repaint(like with disabling and enabling css height property in chromes developer tools).

Comment: @foxx It's always a good idea to provide the actual code, because what you understand your code to be doing may not be what the code is actually doing. Like what if you provide us with pseudocode that does what you intend, but your actual code has a typo? Also, I don't understand how typing out 10 new lines of pseudocode is anywhere comparable in speed to copying and pasting two blocks of code.

Comment: @foxx is this closer to what you need > http://jsbin.com/baroqudafayu/3/ ?

Comment: @flowstoneknight copypasting is obviously faster and smaller effort than typing lines of pseudocode, even if it's just 10 lines. And the actual code was in jsbin, before the pseudo code. Since reproducing the problem requires you to resize your browser, as mentioned in title, you wouldn't be able to tell a thing from the actual code anyway. You simply started commenting before actually properly read the question or clicked the link.

Comment: @webkit that's further to what I need. I want the image to be 100% height. As it is when you load the bin. And I want them to keep being stacked next to each other even on browser resize, which doesn't happen because width of its parent doesn't change.

Comment: and if you shorten your css to    `.item {
  display: inline; 
  img {
    height: 100%;
  }
}`http://jsbin.com/baroqudafayu/13/edit

Comment: it displays i a different way in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jec8tsxh/

Comment: @Akshay that's because jsbin has sass, and jsfiddle doesn't, put that img out of `.item` and it's gonna look the same on fiddle as well. http://jsfiddle.net/fncrdo5y/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

You could rethink your CSS and use the white-space rule to keep your image on 1 line:

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/FvwsH)** ,

**[DEMO FULL PAGE](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/FvwsH/)**

```
html, body, .wrap, .slide , .item, img {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:green;
}
.slide {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.item {
  display:inline;  
  font-size:0.01px;/* kills somehow white-space in HTML code, reset it to childs if any text , like for alt attribute of image that could be usefull */
}
```

[image]
and here : [the inline-block `<li>` version](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ipDHf)

Comment: Probably want to add `.wrap {width:100%; overflow:hidden;}` and the `font-size` in `.item` can be `font-size:0;`.

Comment: @foxx nice screenshot but without any tips of browser used, quiet useless :)

Comment: @flowstoneknight , i do not understand what you mean ? (beside for IE  you better use font-size:0.01px to trigger it , else it has usually no effect.. accessibilty effects)

Comment: Chrome, latest version. And another thing, the whole point of having `.item` there at all, is to be able to add an overlay(and show it on hover), but if you use display inline, item is gonna have height 0px, so absolutely positioned overlay with width and height 100% is gonna have height 0 px as well and won't be visible.

Comment: @GCyrillus I believe the `.wrap` is intended to be a sort of viewport, through which the very wide `.slide` is scrolled using Javascript. That's probably why OP has `width:100%` and `overflow:hidden` in his original code. Just guessing here, since OP didn't provide any information as to what this thing is supposed to be. It also avoids issues with the images changing dimension ratios slightly due to the bottom scrollbar's presence. Didn't know about the `font-size:0` issues. Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @GCyrillus and although inline-block version does work as it should, it's using vh, vw.. and I need it to work on browsers that does not support those.. sorry, for not being clear on that one.

Comment: @foxx , as i commented in the first-place, inline-block is the one giving you trouble :), demo is here to show that you need to refresh it on resize, so this is to be included in your js. For the screen , i do not have this behavior with none of 5 browser on test??  http://i.stack.imgur.com/o4yd6.jpg

Comment: Could be some chrome/mac bug then. Either way I'm kind of looking for the reason why it happens, rather than workarounds, because it is unexpected behaviour, isn't it..

Comment: @foxx yes and no , considering that inline-block triggers a special layout. But, if your `.item` holds only img tags, get rid of them and just keeps image aside along eachothers ;)

Comment: I wouldn't blame inline-block, happens when you use block/float as well http://jsbin.com/baroqudafayu/14/edit?output just to be clear.. this does happen when you resize the browser on windows as well, right? http://i.imgur.com/5PjCSJG.png

Comment: @GCyrillus in the example code it does have only img inside, in actual code it does not, that's why I need it to scale along the img inside.

Comment: @foxx float and inline-block have same effects on layout. Indeed, i do have the same bug , width of .item not resized onresize :)

Comment: Makes me think is *is* a browser bug, it'd be pretty weird if it was intentional that it should behave differently on load and on resize.. on the other hand, if it was a browser bug, wouldn't it work on as least on of the browsers? I'm confused and unsure whether to report it somewhere.

Comment: @foxx i think it is more a matter of ressource, avoiding recalculation of layout each time window is resized, this kind of trouble used to be opera's for years if i remenber and not mistake with some other buggy behavior